# XSLT Selecting parent node where value exists in child

Tags: xml, xslt

How do i select the 'Message' node where any child has the value of 'EXCEPTION'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
<Message>
    <MessageId>1</MessageId>
    <Merchant>
        <Type>Supplier</Type>
        <Id>23</Id>
    </Merchant>
    <Operation>Create</Operation>
    <SKU>AVRCD_002</SKU>
    <Attribute>
        <country>South Africa</country>
        <artist>Anneli Van Rooyen</artist>
        <composer>Anneli Sale</composer>
    </Attribute>
</Message>
<Message>
    <MessageId>2</MessageId>
    <Merchant>
        <Type>Supplier</Type>
        <Id>EXCEPTION</Id>
    </Merchant>
    <Operation>Create</Operation>
    <SKU>AVRCD_002</SKU>
    <Attribute>
        <country>EXCEPTION</country>
        <artist>Anneli Van Rooyen|Lorenzo Tieghi</artist>
        <composer>Sale Anneli</composer>
    </Attribute>
</Message>
</Envelope>
```

The below you need to specify the exact child. I don't want to have to do that. I just want /Message if anything has the value of 'EXCEPTION' within it.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/Envelope/Message[Attribute/country = 'EXCEPTION' or Merchant/Id = 'EXCEPTION']"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, which checks for any descendant text node being equal to "EXCEPTION"

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/Envelope/Message[.//text() = 'EXCEPTION']"/>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, i got close to that but couldnt get it 100%

Comment: But be careful, @LorenzoTieghi, because a node being parent to a text node whose string value is `'EXCEPTION'` is not necessarily the same thing as that node's *own* string value being `'EXCEPTION'`.  A distinction could arise for elements with mixed content.  The former might indeed be exactly what you want, but you should satisfy yourself about that.